# Using Beans in xPages doesn't work

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a simple application with one class and one xPage with one computedField, bound to that class. I want to show result from class getter as a bean. Doesn't work.
My class looks like this:

```
package test.test;

public class Test {
    public Test() {
    }

    public String getTest() {
        return "Test";
    }
}
```

SSJS in the computedField:

```
var test = new test.test.Test();
return test.getTest();
```

an error is like this:

```
Error while executing JavaScript computed expression
Script interpreter error, line=1, col=17: 'test' is undefined

1: var test = new test.test.Test();
```

Am I missing any settings or what?
Thanks in advance, JiKra

EDIT: If I use a managed bean, the issue is absolutely identical. There must be problem with my Designer/Eclipse IDE. I'll try to reinstall it tomorow.

EDIT2: Today, I tried to do the same thing in my colleges's computer and it's the same error. So, the problem is not with my IDE. I must be missing something. Do I need any external libraries to be installed on the server or in the IDE?

Comment: It's just for simplicity. I tried it three times berfore with different package and class names. Still the same error.

Comment: Where is your java class stored? Lib/ext jar, java element?

Comment: It's just a single package and class in Code/Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I did the following.

1) Created a new Java Class.

[image]

2) Put in the following code into the class.

```
package test.test;

public class Test implements java.io.Serializable {

    public Test() {
        super();
    }

    public String getTest() {
        return "Test";
    }

}
```

3) Created an XPage with the following source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var t:test.test.Test = new     test.test.Test();

return t.getTest();
}]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:text>
</xp:view>
```

Opened it in a browser and got the word "Test" appearing.

Changed variable "t" to "test" and then it failed. So it appears the variable name is the issue.

**[EDIT]**

Based on your comment of using 8.5.2, the code/Java functionality didn't arrive until Notes/Domino 8.5.3. Which is why it is not working for you.

Comment: Reproduced in ND9, so I will SPR it.

Comment: OK, but it's not my issue. Last time I tried var myBean = ... and it failed too.

Comment: Was this before or after it failed with "test"? Are you running on server or client? Did you try restarting the client or HTTP if on the server? At this point I'd recommend to post the NSF somewhere to check, or open a PMR.

Comment: I tried the same procedure ten times on three different servers, two different Lotus Notes Designer clients and many different class and variable names. All the same error - an xPage can´t run java bean code.

Comment: What version of Notes/Domino are you using? Can you post a sample NSF somewhere to test with?

Comment: First server is 8.5.2FP3 on linux, second server is 8.5.2FP4HF63 on linux, third server is 8.5.2 on Windows/7/64. You can download one of my sample apps here: http://goo.gl/nkhHf

Comment: @JiKra: try to change packade. seems the problem is with ambiguation of package and variable. keeping with Java best practices would help ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your variable name in SSJS (test) is conflicting with the package name. Use

```
var test1=new test.test.Test();
```

It will work...

Comment: Sorry, but it simply doesn't work. I tried various names, different applications and two servers. Last I used var test1 = new johny.Money(); test1.getMyMoney(); Still not working. Maybe there is something wrong with my Designer. Tomorow, I will try a different one on different computer.

Comment: I just tried the exact code with test1 and it worked. Did you try cleaning and rebuilding?

Answer (score 1):

Probably build issue. Make sure you...

1) Built the code, try to clean and build.

2) Have correct build paths - you find it in preferences dialog.

3) Can locate Test.class file, preferably in Navigator view of Java perspective.

Comment: 1. Tried many times. 2. Java\Build Path? 3. Class file is located in WebContent\WEB-INF\classes\test\test\Test.class

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the Java and XPage are built after you have changed the package name. For example add a `print("new XPage")` to SSJS and `System.out.println("new Java")` to Java.

I can reproduce the problem with your code and 8.5.3FP3 Designer+Server. When I change the package name to **test.tes** the problem goes away.

EDIT: I used variable name "t" all the time and can confirm that the problem appears **also** if I change the variable name to "test" as Simon found out below. Maybe Simon has a different Desiger/Domino version because `test.test.Test` does not work for me with variable name "t".

EDIT2: Sounds like you are using 8.5.3 Designer with 8.5.2 server. As Simon said Code/Java was introduced in 8.5.3. Instructions for writing Java for 8.5.2 can be found for example here: http://xpageswiki.com/web/youatnotes/wiki-xpages.nsf/dx/Work_with_Java

Answer (score 0):

While initializing you Java class in SSJS the code should be like this:

```
var testObj:test.test.Test = new test.test.Test();
```

Comment: Just an FYI but that "var testObj:test.test.Test" is only for the SSJS editor to provide type ahead, even though it doesn't for custom classes

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put the new statement.

```
var test = new test.test.Test();
```

Comment: No, I didn't. I just forgot tu put it here. My mistake. Even with new statement it doesn't work. Same error...

Comment: Done :-) And there is more. See Edit2.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the issue, but I think you have to define a variable "test" of type String in the Bean in order to retrieve it's value using getTest().

Comment: No, he does not bind (and even with bindig it wouldn't be a problem), he just calls getTest() on new instance.